# Why was Captain America not wearing his helmet during battle of Sokovia

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, in Sokovia, Ultron plans to use the city as a meteor to destroy mankind. All of the Avengers were there in their suits fighting back. Captain America had his whole outfit and shield except the helmet he wears.

So why didn't he wear his helmet during the battle? The helmet was gone once Cap came back from Korea to Avengers Tower so he can tell Tony to shut Vison down and it was gone from that point to the end. Where was it?

Comment: More face time?

Comment: I don't think a leather mask is really going to help much when the entire city comes crashing down and destroys all life on the planet.

Comment: Are you asking: Does Captain America change clothes? Could he leave home without his helmet? This question seems so broad as to not have a definitive answer...

Comment: Either one will do

Comment: @phantom42 I bet that in addition to leather, it contains other materials -- possibly Kevlar or something even more advanced.  Military helmets don't stop bullets for the most part, but they're still considered extremely important, protecting against shrapnel, debris, blows the head, etc.  It is foolish for a character to not wear one into battle when he/she has one.  But I understand that this is common in movies.

Comment: I can't think of an in-universe explanation.  The out-of-universe explanation is http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HelmetsAreHardlyHeroic

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you're going to get a legitimate in-universe answer here. This is a case of it's actually a movie and the powers that be wanted to show more of the actors faces they were spending millions of dollars on.

Comment: Maybe Cap just doesn't like wearing his helmet. It could be uncomfortably warm to wear it all the time.

Answer (score 4):

During the final battle against Ultron in Sokovia, Captain America was not wearing his helmet in order to make the Sokovian citizens to see him as a person, rather than a symbol of war. In a deleted scene from AoU, Cap sees a mural on a wall depicting the Avengers as warmongers, and this is what influences his decision to take off his helmet.

Like he said, evacuating the Sokovian citizens was first priority, fighting Ultron and his army was secondary.

Comment: Out-universe wise, Chris Evans wanted to show his pretty face ^_^