# Why was there a motorcycle on the USS Franklin?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[image]

In Star Trek Beyond, while Montgomery Scott is giving Captain Kirk the cook's tour of the Altamid-grounded USS Franklin, they just so happen to come across a full-functional BX-70 motorcycle - one very similar to the one his uncle owned in Star Trek 2009. This will be important later when they dream up a distraction. Fine, but there are some questions we need to address with this:

- How is it possible that a motorcycle is on a starship?
- And, shouldn't Captain Kirk be wearing a helmet?

Comment: Kirk is not wearing a helmet because he is Kirk.

Comment: @Adamant - Kirk is not wearing a helmet because you don't pay Chris Pine $6m then stick his face behind a helmet.

Comment: @Valorum - Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128252/51379

Comment: @Adamant - More than related. Dupe :-)

Comment: Well in the original timeline dune buggies were apparently included in Sovereign class starships (see Star Trek Nemesis).  A dune buggy would have taken up too much room on the USS Franklin, so they settled for a dirt bike. :)

Comment: Same reason why war vets come home with souvenirs from their service.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think there **wouldn't** be motorcycles on a starship? Does it make sense to you that you can zip across the light-years in a starship to another planet, and when you get there you have to trudge on foot? I assume they are equipped with cars, trucks, tanks, boats and aircraft — ***why not motorcycles?***

Comment: Yep, most Starfleet ships are actually pretty large, and we barely see even 5% of most ships on screen. Once replicators come onto the scene, there shouldn't be any reason that a crew couldn't replicate basic vehicles or at least the parts to assemble basic vehicles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is very likely the same reason as in the babylon 5 series (in universe at least): A commanding officer is a big fan of motorcycles / the old times and used all contacts he had to get one on board.

Out of universe: Because the writers found it cool (at least that is my impression in both cases).

Edit:
Non motorcycle examples of this are archers dog, datas cat, ...

And for the second question: The helmet is not there for recognition (out of universe) and coolness(out of universe)  and in universe (probably no helmet lying around and kirk being too much kirk to wear one).

Comment: I think your answer is akin to Captain Archer having a dog on board.

Comment: @JerryNixon-TOS yepp that is another example or data having a cat,.... (babylon 5 though had the only other motorcycle I know of)

Answer (score 5):

### In-universe

Unknown at the present time. It almost certainly belonged to one of the ship's crew. There's no recognition of the bike from Krall but beyond that, we just don't know.

### Out of Universe

This was apparently a "shout out" by director Justin Lin to his earlier films in the '[Fast & Furious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Lin#The_Fast_and_the_Furious_franchise)' franchise.

> *"Yeah, and I don’t know if that’s the case here. When I saw the teaser,
> I’m like, aw shit.  **You really have to put the motorcycle in there? So
> I get it, I get it, I get it."***
>
> ***When someone else brings up the shot that looks very reminiscent of
> Letty-Dom flying through the air from the Fast & Furious films, Justin
> smiles and smirks, “Yeah, well I’m who I am.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Justin Lin on ‘Star Trek Beyond’ Criticisms: “We Are Trying to Be Bold and Take Risks”](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-trek-beyond-criticisms/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: And yes, he should be wearing a helmet. Safety first, people.

Comment: Doesn't need a helmet, could assume the bike has some sort of stabilization system that prevents more common incidents. Also, thats not Letty and Dom jumping those bikes, its two of the bad guy (johnny tran) henchmen

Comment: The point that Krall does not recognize the bike is relevant.

Comment: @JerryNixon-TOS - Sure,  but it's also worth noting that Krall has become a compete nutjob after hundreds of years of mental degradation